# split columns in R with regex

Tags: r, dplyr

how can I transform the first data frame like the second with regex expressions or any other way

```r
  df <- data.frame (element  = c("Autres produits d'exploitation 918,306"),V2 = c("2"), V3=c("676")
  ) 
  
  newdf <- data.frame (element  = c("Autres produits d'exploitation"),V2 = c("2 676 918,306")
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0.9002)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you were looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(readr)

df %>%
  unite("V2", V2:V3, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(V2 = paste(V2, readr::parse_number(element), sep = " "), 
         element = str_remove(element, as.character(parse_number(df$element, 
                                                                 locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")))))

                          element           V2
1 Autres produits d'exploitation  2 676 918306
```